# Applying formula on Timestamp in milliseconds in C++ gives me 0 always?

Tags: c++, timestamp, uint64

I have a method below which will accept `oldTimestamp` as the input parameter which is `uint64_t`... Now I need to apply a formula on the above `oldTimestamp` and whenever I apply that formula, I always get `0` as `start` value.

And also I try to get the `current timestamp` in milliseconds in the same method which is `long int` data type (not sure whether this is right datatype) and whenever I apply the same formula again on the `currentTimestamp`, I always get `end` value as `0` as well...

Below is my method -

```
void getRecord(uint64_t oldTimestamp) {

    int start = (oldTimestamp / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24))  % 14;

    cout<<"START: " << start <<endl; // this always print out as 0..?

    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);

    long int currentTimestamp = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000; //get current timestamp in milliseconds

    int end = (currentTimestamp / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24))  % 14;

    cout<<"END: " << end <<endl; // this always print out as 0 as well..?

}
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

Might be, I am using wrong Data Type for currentTimestamp and oldTimestamp and I should not use `int` for `start` and `end`?

**Update:-**

Something like this will be fine?

```
void getRecord(uint64_t oldTimestamp) {

    uint64_t start = (oldTimestamp / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24))  % 14;

    cout<<"START: " << start <<endl;

    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);

    uint64_t currentTimestamp = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000; //get current timestamp in milliseconds

    uint64_t end = (currentTimestamp / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24))  % 14;

    cout<<"END: " << end <<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void getRecord(uint64_t oldTimestamp) { // you are using uint64_t here

int start = (oldTimestamp / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24))  % 14; // you are using int here
```

You are likely running into an overflow issue, which is invoking undefined behavior.

You need to use `uint64_t` as your `start` type.  The same goes for your `currentTimestamp` and `end` variables.

Comment: I updated my question with the correct code.. Can you take a look and let me know if everything looks good to you?

Comment: You may also want to add the proper suffixes to your constants:  `60LL * 60LL * 1000LL * 24LL`, etc.  I would also suggest you actually do the math and use a single constant (though, your compiler will likely do that for you ... it just makes it more readable to have a single constant instead of carrying around a constant expression literal everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using int for start and end.